# How to invoke a Web Service that requires the "patch" verb using the C# WebClient wrapper?

Tags: c#, rest, webclient, patch, http-status-code-401

Our ASP.NET C# web application is used in the following environment -

-.NET Framework 4
 - IIS 7
 - Windows 2008
 - Visual Studio 2012
- .NET IDE
 - C#
 - HTTPS ( SSL )

The Web Service Endpoint is on a third-party vendor.
The Web Service Endpoint uses the "patch" verb.

The third-party vendor specifications require that the Web Service Endpoint

1)  needs an bigInt id for a particular resource 
2) a "patch" verb

```
String address = string.Format("https://blah.blah.com/users/{0}?verb={1}",
                  Uri.EscapeDataString(vfuArg.ViaFouraUserId.ToString()), Uri.EscapeDataString("patch"));
```

However, the specifications also allows for other arguments that are Not in the url of the web service.
The specifications are pretty brief.

I have named-value pairs declared as follows:

```
var values = new NameValueCollection{  { "email", loggedInUserRegisteredEmailArg }  };
```

I uploaded the data as follows:

```
    byte[] result = clientArg.UploadValues(address, values);
    var clientResponseForModifyingUser = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
```

However, I get a 401 error.

Am I invoking "patch" verb properly with C# WebClient wrapper?  I failed to find much online documentation on "patch" verb and the C# WebClient.

What should I change in the code snippets listed above in order to resolve the issue?

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue. Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: The Third-party company who provided us the Web Services API had Out-of-Date technical documentation so they emailed us the correct way to code.

Answer (score 2):

The "verb" usually means the http method... "GET", POST", etc. It does not go on the query-string - it is specified in the call itself:

```
byte[] result = clientArg.UploadValues(address, "PATCH", values);
```

Comment: I changed my Web Service invocation url to String address = string.Format("https://api.viafoura.com/v2/dev.viafoura.com/users/{0}", Uri.EscapeDataString(vfuArg.ViaFouraUserId.ToString())); along with your suggested code byte[] result = clientArg.UploadValues(address, "PATCH", values); . However, it still fails.

Comment: @user1338998 are there any example of their API working? you might want to run something like fiddler over the examples...